# deleting a file in c# after sending email attachment

Tags: c#

I have the following code that basically attaches a file to an email message then after all attachments are attached and email is sent, i try to delete all files, however I get a file in use exception.  I believe the error comes in this line

```
Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);
```

I tried using this code but I get an cannot sent email message

```
using Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet)){
//and the rest of the code in here.

}


foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kvp in reports) {
    browser.GoTo(kvp.Value);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\Reports\bidata.csv", @"C:\Reports\"+kvp.Key.ToString()+".csv");

    string file = @"C:\Reports\" + kvp.Key.ToString() + ".csv";

    Attachment data = new Attachment(file, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet);

    // Add time stamp information for the file.
    ContentDisposition disposition = data.ContentDisposition;
    disposition.CreationDate = System.IO.File.GetCreationTime(file);
    disposition.ModificationDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(file);
    disposition.ReadDate = System.IO.File.GetLastAccessTime(file);
    // Add the file attachment to this e-mail message.

    mail.Attachments.Add(data);  
}

smtpserver.Send(mail);
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Reports");
foreach (string files1 in files)
{
    File.Delete(files1);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to delete the files first you will have to dispose the attachment and mail objects and then delete the files

Answer (score 3):

Dispose the smtpclient by putting it in a usings or calling dispose directly.  That should free the file resource and allow you to nuke it.